# Is there a way to describe what side of the polygon is "inside"

Tags: jts-topology-suite

Let's say I want to create a polygon of northern half of earth, the line string of the polygon will be on the equator. In JTS (Java) with SRID 4326 is there a way to say if the north side of Earth or south side of Earth is the "inside" part of the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTS is a planar geometry system and has no concept of SRID so, no.

From the [FAQ](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/jts-faq.html#B5):

> JTS uses the implicit coordinate system of the input data. The only assumption it makes is that the coordinate system is **infinite, planar and Euclidean** (i.e. rectilinear and obeying the standard Euclidean distance metric). In the same way JTS does not specify any particular units for coordinates and geometries. Instead, the units are implicitly defined by the input data provided. This implies that in most cases input geometries to operations should be defined with the same coordinate system.

Note the added emphasis - Geometries in EPSG:4326 are not really well defined in JTS, for small ones you might get away with it if you are careful but for hemispheres not so much.

Comment: If I understand correctly I can not describe the polygon in the question with JTS? will it fail or just be ambiguous?

Comment: It will be ambiguous and operations on it will likely produce incorrect results

Comment: IN EPSG 4326 the northern hemisphere of the earth is a rectangle defined by the four points of  `POLYGON ((-180 0, 180 0, 180 90, -180 90, -180 0))` but I defer to Ian's knowledge on how JTS will cope with a polygon like that.